# Combining 3 values with User::lists in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Currently I am doing this to pass a list of users into my view:

```
$users = User::lists('name', 'id');
return View::make('admin.gifs.add')->with('user_list', $users);
```

The view looks like this:

```
{{ Form::select('owner-id', $user_list, NULL, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

This works great and outputs `name` in the select field with a value of `id`. What I'd like to do is show both `name` and `email` inside the select field. Is this possible?

I tried something like `$users = User::lists('name', 'email', 'id');` which didn't work, is there some way to combined them and have the values of my `select` be something like `First Last [email@domain.com]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hack this together with `CONCAT` in a raw query, but it's not worth it.

Instead, construct the list yourself:

```php
$users = [];

User::all()->each(function ($user) use (&$users)
{
    $users[$user->id] = "{$user->name} [{$user->email}]";
});

return View::make('admin.gifs.add')->with('user_list', $users);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$users = User::lists('name','email','id');
```

Then you have to modify the resulting array so that it contains two values instead of three.

```
$correctList = [];
foreach ($users as $u) {
   $correctList[] = [$u->name . $u->email, $u->id];
}
```

Then pass the new list to the view and you're done.

Comment: Are you sure you can pass several column names to Model::lists() ?Which version of Laravel is it?